# How To: set A4 size in a WPF usercontrol?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a custom "canvas" (MyUserControl) in WPF.

I need to be able to set that "canvas" to the paper size (A3, A4 etc or even custom).

How should I transform the `A4` in the `Width` and `Height` of the MyUserControl?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469495/how-to-use-a-different-coordinate-system-in-wpf-scaling-only), I can do (for A4):

```
Height="29.7cm" Width="21cm"
```

even if in the code this became more complicated...

Answer (score 2):

maybe I don't understand your question the right way, but MSDN defines Width/Height as

> *"This value is interpreted as a device-independent unit (1/96th inch) measurement. Strings need not explicitly include decimal points. For
>   instance a value of 1 is acceptable."*

see [FrameworkElement.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx)

Based on the Unit of `1/96th Inch` you could simply convert the paper size to it's `px` representation.

HTH,

--hennson

Answer (score 0):

To set size for A4 printing

A4 Width = (8 * 96)px  Height = (11.5 * 96)px

A3 = Simply double the width (16 * 96)px

Don't forget printer border, but the above will always print A4 sheet

I know everything nowadays is metric, but math is easier using inches . . .

A4 = 297mm * 210mm but also is 8" * 11.5", hence the above math works!